# Why is `lineplot()` not working in Seaborn and how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

seaborn `lineplot()` is not working. I am using jupyter notebook and Ubuntu to run python code. I have installed seaborn using pip command. While working with seaborn, I found out that the `lineplot()` function is not working as well as other functions like `relplot(kind="line", ----)`, `displot(kde=True, ------)`, etc. which involves "line" are not working.
what could be the possible cause for this? what is the solution?

I tried the following code and got the following error.

My Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
may_flights = flights.query("month == 'May'")
sns.lineplot(data=may_flights, x="year", y="passengers")
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_16738/552005642.py in <module>
      1 flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
      2 may_flights = flights.query("month == 'May'")
----> 3 sns.lineplot(data=may_flights, x="year", y="passengers")

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in lineplot(data, x, y, hue, size, style, units, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, dashes, markers, style_order, estimator, errorbar, n_boot, seed, orient, sort, err_style, err_kws, legend, ci, ax, **kwargs)
    643     kwargs["color"] = _default_color(ax.plot, hue, color, kwargs)
    644 
--> 645     p.plot(ax, kwargs)
    646     return ax
    647 

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in plot(self, ax, kws)
    457                     lines.extend(ax.plot(unit_data["x"], unit_data["y"], **kws))
    458             else:
--> 459                 lines = ax.plot(sub_data["x"], sub_data["y"], **kws)
    460 
    461             for line in lines:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1630         """
   1631         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633         for line in lines:
   1634             self.add_line(line)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in __call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310                 this += args[0],
    311                 args = args[1:]
--> 312             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    313 
    314     def get_next_color(self):

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    485 
    486         if len(xy) == 2:
--> 487             x = _check_1d(xy[0])
    488             y = _check_1d(xy[1])
    489         else:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py in _check_1d(x)
   1325                     message='Support for multi-dimensional indexing')
   1326 
-> 1327                 ndim = x[:, None].ndim
   1328                 # we have definitely hit a pandas index or series object
   1329                 # cast to a numpy array.

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1031             return self._get_values(key)
   1032 
-> 1033         return self._get_with(key)
   1034 
   1035     def _get_with(self, key):

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_with(self, key)
   1046             )
   1047         elif isinstance(key, tuple):
-> 1048             return self._get_values_tuple(key)
   1049 
   1050         elif not is_list_like(key):

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_values_tuple(self, key)
   1080             # the asarray is needed to avoid returning a 2D DatetimeArray
   1081             result = np.asarray(self._values[key])
-> 1082             disallow_ndim_indexing(result)
   1083             return result
   1084 

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers/utils.py in disallow_ndim_indexing(result)
    341     """
    342     if np.ndim(result) > 1:
--> 343         raise ValueError(
    344             "Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer "
    345             "supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead."

ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.
```

Comment: You have the reason and the solution in the stacktrace `Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. obj[:, None]) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.` `data` should be a dataframe or numpy array.

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnWSO.png). People often have installation issues between their system python, and other versions they may have installed. You should try updating matplotlib, pandas, and numpy.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.